# Response Method not there with Sinatra, Rspec & Capybara

Tags: rspec, sinatra, capybara

I'm trying to use Capybara + Rspec to test a Sinatra app, and I'm having some trouble integrating Capybara with Rspec. Here's my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require './myapp'
require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.app = MyApp
```

Then, in my `app_spec.rb`, I have:

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe "My App", type: :request do
    describe "get 'home'" do
        it "should be successful" do
            visit '/'
            response.should be_successful
        end
    end
end
```

According to all the documentation I can find, this should work fine . . . but when I run `rspec spec`, I get this:

```
Failures:

  1) Our App get 'home' should be successful
     Failure/Error: response.should be_successful
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007f8321289e60>
     # ./spec/app_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've done a bit of digging around, and I can solve the problem by throwing this method into the spec file:

```
def response 
    page.driver.browser.last_response
end
```

But that feels hacky.

Is there a better solution? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is no response method. I think that's only in the Rails addons for RSpec2/Capybara (not sure about this).

Just use `last_response` instead of `response`:

```
last_response.should be_successful
```

and you should be fine.

**Edit:** 
Seems like you are missing some test methods. Try this in your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

You will need to require `rack/test` before.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem . . . although now I'm getting `undefined local variable or method 'app'`, but that's probably another issue. I'll have to poke around some more :)

Comment: It was coming from the same file, same place. I fixed it by adding `def app; MyApp.new; end` to my `spec_helper.rb`. However, now the `fill_in` method is saying it can't find my text input elements,  element that `have_selector` can find. So, I'm guessing that Capybara wasn't meant to go with Sinatra + Rspec :)

Comment: @Andrew: You could try [Webrat](https://github.com/brynary/webrat) instead of capybara. I've built a template here: [sinatra-rspec-bundler-template](https://github.com/daddz/sinatra-rspec-bundler-template) Maybe the code helps you a bit